# Surface Go will not boot from USB

Tags: tablet, usb-installation, surface

I have a 128GB Microsoft Surface Go (the non-LTE version) running Ubuntu 19.10 ("Eoan Ermine"), and I am trying to "clean" install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa")... But I have not yet been able to get the tablet to boot from the USB "thumb" drive.

I have been trying to use a USB "thumb" drive that has been *successfully* used with *multiple* other computers, of different models from different manufacturers.

Thus far, I have:

- Verified the boot order in the UEFI (i.e. made sure that "USB" is the first device used for booting);
- Tried with and without secure boot enabled;
- Tried with and without the trusted platform module enabled;
- Tried multiple USB "thumb" drives, with separately-download images, in case the original one was corrupt (though this was always going to be *unlikely* because as noted above, this has *repeatedly* been used *without* issue);
- Tried various button combinations as discussed online in "official" documentation;
- Tried various "alternate" button presses that seemed logical (e.g. holding or pressing "Shift" or various "function" keys during boot-up);
- Tried downloading a recovery image as discussed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023512/surface-creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive), though what I am seeing is different to what is described (probably because I used a Linux laptop to do this, working it out as I went - those instructions are for someone using a Microsoft Windows-based computer), so thus far it hasn't been of much use (still working on it);
- Tried booting an old copy of Microsoft Windows 8 to install it and then somehow use Windows 8 to *force* booting from the USB "thumb" drive - I couldn't get this to work because I'd see the "press a key to boot from DVD" message, but pressing keys would not work and it'd start booting Ubuntu. There is nothing wrong with the keyboard-cover - it works fine when booted into Ubuntu 19.10 ("Eoan Ermine") - and the external keyboard I tried to use has also been tested as working without issue.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I fixed it... But it took a bit of mucking around.

First I downloaded and installed a "pirate" copy of Microsoft Windows 10 (single-boot setup) and then I tried to boot from a USB "thumb" drive using the instructions Microsoft provide online (I haven't used a Microsoft operating system - outside of *very* light usage at work - in nearly ten years)... No luck, it still wouldn't boot from the USB "thumb" drive.

In fact, no matter what I did, I simply could *not* get it to boot from the USB "thumb" drive.

So I copied a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa") image to a USB Type-C "thumb" drive instead (I was *originally* using a "traditional" USB "thumb" drive via an adaptor), changed the boot order around a bit (it was already on the *correct* boot order, but I figured this might "refresh" the boot order) and then restarted... Voila - it worked!

**Okay, disclaimer time.**

I used a "pirate" copy of Windows 10 - *but I have no intention of using this operating system* (most of our computers run Ubuntu, and the few exceptions run Apple macOS) - *it was deleted immediately after I got Ubuntu running on my Microsoft Surface Go*... In total, I used this operating system for about five minutes, almost all of which was me logging in and restarting.

If you intend to dual-boot or use Windows 10 on another device, *please* buy a license - Microsoft as a company might have its many flaws, but behind the "big evil corporation", there are actually a *lot* of developers that worked *awfully hard* on this operating system... So please, *please* buy a license if you want to continue using Windows 10.

On a side-note, I later found a "trial" copy of Windows 10 on Microsoft's web site - so you should *probably* use this instead of a "pirate" copy...

Comment: A couple of questions - just out of curiosity: 1. What type is the filesystem on your thumb drive? 2. BIOS on your tablet - is it secured EFI or not?

Comment: The filesystem on the USB "thumbdrive" was whatever filesysttem Ubuntu uses by default when burning an ISO to a USB "thumb" drive via "Startup Disk Creator" (I can't check now - I wiped the USB "thumb" drive)... Microsoft Windows 10 was an exception, because apparently Windows 10 has "special requirements" for a bootable USB, so I had to find the only copy of Windows we had in the house (an old copy of Microsoft Windows 8) and use some random program Etcher recommended to create a bootable USB "thumb" drive with Windows 10 on it.

Comment: As for the UEFI - the Microsoft Surface products, like almost all computers these days, don't use a BIOS anymore - yes, it has Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: By default Ubuntu makes installer USB thumbdrive with ISO9660 file system. I suppose the Surface's bios just does not recognize it. Look through this my answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1235778/847672

Comment: ISO9660 is naturally read-only. In order to add or delete a file in it you need to recalculate all its structure. On the other hand, Windows installer thumbdrive uses FAT or NTFS, both writable.