# Getting Ubuntu on to our Linx. 1010 window touch tablet

Tags: boot, system-installation, tablet

Hello Everyone how are you all. I have a Linx 1010 windows 10 tablet and for about a week I have been trying to get Ubuntu on there I have been looking at youtube video's and asking people on a Ubuntu facebook group and know one has been able to help me can you ? please thank you for your help.

Comment: there is a easier way to install.
Create bootable ubuntu 20 usb stick.
boot windows into troubleshooting mode, go to advances and you can acccess the uefi on there.
see link to details on how to do it.
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5831-boot-uefi-firmware-settings-inside-windows-10-a.html
I installed ubuntu 20 no problems everything works touchscreen, sound etc, except the cameras which i'm trying to sort now.
good luck

Answer (score 1):

The problems with most of those tablets are:

1. EFI boot system support only 32-bit mode while the system is 64-bit.
2. BIOS does not support ISO9660 filesystem (on USB drives?)

Good thing is that you actually can install Ubuntu on it :-)

I can not describe the process in exact details because different bios versions *are* different. But the main steps are:

1. Find bootia32.efi file (suggest Github) and download it.
2. Make USB "installer". Format it FAT32 and copy the contents of  original Ubuntu installer ISO file to it. I am not sure about should the USB disk be bootable or not (looks like it does not matter).
3. Copy bootia32.efi to the USB disk under \EFI\BOOT or similar. Copy any other stuff you want.
4. Boot your tablet to BIOS with the USB disk connected
5. Sometimes to gain access to all EFI options you have to setup supervisor password in your tablet BIOS - so do it. After everything works you can disable (clear) it back.
6. Specify path to bootia32.efi in BIOS EFI as trusted file
7. Either set USB disk as first boot option or enable boot option selection (F12 usually)
8. Good idea is to enable network access during install through wired usb adapter - do it.
9. Boot the tablet from USB disk and install Ubuntu, allow download modules during install.
10. After install is finished, remove USB disk, boot to BIOS and specify path to groobia32.efi **on fixed disk (NOT USB)** as trusted. You can remove the BIOS supervisor password now.
11. Here your tablet should boot to Ubuntu normally.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am trying to do what you have said to do. God Bless you.